# How can I use DTrace on Yosemite with Ruby 2.2.2?

Tags: ruby, dtrace

I've configured and installed Ruby 2.2.2 with DTrace enabled (`--enable-dtrace`).

It appears to have done so successfully: "checking whether dtrace USDT is available... yes" and "dtrace" on another check (instead of "no").

Testing with:

`sudo dtrace  -c 'ruby -v' -l -m ruby`

Returns:

`dtrace: failed to match :ruby::: No probe matches description`

I did see [dtrace probes missing on yosemite system ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221324/dtrace-probes-missing-on-yosemite-system-ruby), but that's RVM and I install with a local user account (sudo-less).

Has someone with a similar configuration made this work and, if so, how?

Thanks.

Also: `RbConfig::CONFIG['DTRACE']` outputs `dtrace` in IRB.

I've Googled and DDG'd the heck out of this question, so I think an answer from someone's own experience would be necessary to help...

Comment: Following this guide: http://www.ploughthroughruby.co.uk/2013/04/10/dtrace-probes-in-ruby-2.html/, I can modify the probe to specify "ruby*:::method-entry" (three colons required, versus the two in the post) and see output "dtrace: description 'ruby*:::method-entry ' matched 2 probes." However there's no columnar output specifying classes and access counts.